# Hyphenating a term that has spaces

Tags: hyphenation

I would typically use the term "electric field" like so: "[...] therefore, it has a high electric field". If I wanted to hyphenate this term with a compound word, how would I do so?

Someone mentioned that "Electric-field-induced voltage" is appropriate, but I believe
"Electric field-induced voltage" is (no hyphen in between electric and field added). Which is it?

Comment: Some would use << electric-field-induced voltage >> whereas some  recommend << electric-field–induced voltage >> where the hyphen indicates the stronger bond ('electric field' being a compound, open in standalone usage as you say).

Comment: Interesting take with the en-dash! Thanks.